# Execute code when QWidget is actually destroyed, not just closed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, destroy

I have created a custom `QDialog` class and overridden the `closeEvent` to just hide the dialog as it is a child of another widget. My dialog must only close when its parent is closed and not when it's accepted, rejected or the user clicks the close button.

This all works fine but now I need to open a connection to a database and only close it when the dialog is destroyed not just when it's closed.

My code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

def Log_Closed():
    print "Bye bye"

class My_dlg(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__( self, parent )

        #self.conn = open_connection()
        print "Connection Opened"

        close_btn  = QPushButton("Actually Close")
        QVBoxLayout(self).addWidget(close_btn)

        close_btn.clicked.connect(self.Actually_Close)
        self.destroyed.connect(Log_Closed)

    def Actually_Close(self):
        print "Actually Close"
        self.parent().close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Close:
            event.ignore()
            self.hide()
            print "hidden"

    # And I guess I need something like
    def destroyEvent(self, event):
        #self.conn.close()
        print "Connection Closed"
        event.accept()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main= QMainWindow()
    tsd = My_dlg(main)
    tsd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If the dialog should only close when it's parent is closed, why not just use the parent's `closeEvent` to do the necessary cleanup actions?

Comment: I've created a small python app that loads in files that run various dialogs and to keep it dynamic everything that gets defined in one of the child dialogs needs to stay in there. I don't want to close a connection that was opened in the child in the parent as this defeats the purpose of my setup. Thanks though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To receive notification when a `QObject` is deleted, connect to its [`destroyed(QObject*)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#destroyed) signal.

However, in Python, object deletion is less predictable than it is in C++ because objects are garbage collected. For example, see all of the caveats associated with `__del__()` in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__). They may not be deleted when the program exits, which is probably why you're not receiving the signal.

Instead of relying on deletion of the dialog, you could manage the database connection explicitly. In this simple example, you could even use a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html) for slightly nicer code.

---

Either way, here's a version of your code that behaves as you expect: https://gist.github.com/3827718

The changes I made were:

- Set `app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed` to make sure that the application doesn't quit when the dialog closes. I presume this is the behavior you want, because otherwise this question doesn't make sense.
- Set `Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose` to `False` on the dialog to prevent it from deleting itself when closed. This is preferable to overriding `closeEvent`.
- In `Actually_Close()`, the dialog deletes itself (which will also close it). This triggers the `destroyed` signal.

With this code, the output is as you expect when you click the button:

```
Connection Opened
Actually Close
Bye bye
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Initially I thought that too but I tried it but it didn't seem to do anything so I thought I was doing something wrong. Anyway I have updated my code to include the destroyed connection but as before it doesn't seem to work. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't read your example closely enough. Because Python uses garbage collection, object lifetimes have more subtle behaviors than they do in C++. In particular, Python doesn't guarantee that objects will be deleted on program exit, so I suspect that's what is going on here. I'll try to clarify a bit.